# Difference between su command for Fedora and Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, root, su

To log in as root while using Fedora I use :

```
su
```

and then enter the password.

But while using Ubuntu this fails even if I use the correct password. But if I enter:

```
su -s
```

and then enter the password, I am successfully able to log in as root. What is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root account is disabled in Ubuntu by default. You can't log in as root, even with `su`.

You can have more details on the [community website's documentation.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)

I have, however, no idea as why invoking a specific shell will allow you to log.
Did you, by chance, mean `sudo -s`, and not `su -s`?

Comment: He probably did. `su -s` gives an error since a shell needs to be specified. The standard way of getting a root shell using `sudo` is `sudo -i`.

Comment: To clarify: There is no root password in Ubuntu by default (_not_ an empty password, _no_ password). You can't be typing the right password, because noting will match the stored hash.